# Identifying a SF story about explorers on a strange planet travelling down a slowly steepening slope

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think this story is at least 40 or 50 years old as I mainly read classic SF when I was a teenager.
All I can remember about it is some explorers or soldiers were exploring an enormous seemingly endless featureless plain that starts as a gentle slope and then gets steeper and steeper over the days.
I can't remember anything about the characters, or how the story ends. I just remember the creepiness of the featureless slope getting steeper and steeper.

Comment: I remember a story like this.  Does it turn out to be a predator's trap or maw?

Comment: It also reminds me of *Inverted World*, but the word "featureless" doesn't fit.

Answer (score 45):

[**Mouth of Hell**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57103) by David I. Masson

The explorers on the new planet find a deep hole in the planet's surface. It starts as a gentle slope but gets steeper and steeper. They only manage to get a couple of kilometres down before the atmospheric pressure becomes too much to stand.

A few years later a specially build aircraft tries to find the bottom, but cannot quite make it. Radar says the bottom is forty two kilometres below the planet's surface.

Thirty years later the bottom is reached, and ... but that would be a spoiler.

Comment: The title seems to explain it well.....

Comment: Feel free to use spoiler formatting to include spoilers, they will be hidden by default and only revealed if the user explicitly asks for it.

Comment: While the use of spoiler formatting would help get a more complete answer, I find it's much better with a cliffhanger, because it made me instantly want to read the story!

Comment: I was already a David I. Masson fan based on one story, but now I am so all the more and think he must be the master of nonlinear gradients.

Comment: [Text online here](https://ae.ansible.uk/pdf/caltraps-sample.pdf).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - It's not much of a spoiler.

Comment: This is why I like story id questions.

Comment: I always thought that story could be made into a long calm movie with slowly advancing caterpillared vehicles, where nothing happens at all and conversations can be had where much is left unstated, like the movie adaptation of [The Tartar Steppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tartar_Steppe)

Comment: @martin given the slow change in steepness, it is not much of a cliffhanger,is it?

Comment: @Valorum: I've just read it and now I know what you mean. I think this story exemplifies what they mean over on [writing.se] when they tell you that worldbuilding alone doesn't make a story ;)

Comment: @yrodro I meant that the answer itself doesn't reveal the spoiler, thus building up a kind of cliffhanger in the answer. I didn't mean the story.

Comment: @Martin I am aware ;)

Answer (score 2):

While it is a bit of a long shot,  there are some overlapping features with "[The Inverted World](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_World)" by Christopher Priest.

Since you remember so little, perhaps,  some of the details you remember are in fact a bit different.  So:

> I think this story is at least 40 or 50 years old as I mainly read classic SF when I was a teenager.

Published in 1974, and a SF classic.

> some explorers or soldiers were exploring

The main protagonist is at some point an explorer, charting the terrain ahead and some time behind the moving city he is from.

> an enormous seemingly endless featureless plain that starts as a gentle slope and then gets steeper and steeper over the days.

The terrain is not a featureless plain, however, as the explorer moves further away from the city,  he experiences strange physical phenomena,  among other things, the terrain is sloping steeper and steeper,  until at some point he sees before him (as far as I remember) an endless vertical wall of terrain disappearing topside.

> I just remember the creepiness of the featureless slope getting steeper and steeper.

I don't have quotes, but the descriptions deal a lot with the physical weirdness of the world.

I don't want to reveal spoilers, but the world in question appears to be

> not a spheroid, but a [tractricoid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere#Tractricoid)

Comment: On the depicted tractricoid, where exactly do you have a slope that gets increasingly steep?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the plot section of the Wikipedia entry shows the idea of the world,  I think better than I can describe it here.

Answer (score -4):

I sounds a bit like "Rendezvous with Rama" from Arthur C Clarke.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how it matches the description given in the question? It would help OP to judge whether this is the correct story or not.

Comment: The slope in Rama gets gradually shallower until it's entirely horizontal, and there are plenty of features (ladders, staircases, landings, etc.).

Comment: Moreover, Rama was definitely not "on a planet" nor "seemingly endless".